Proxy works on Node.js but not as a web proxy
When I use free proxies on with node.js (whether it's a WebSocket or simple GET requests) they work, but when I try to use that proxy as a proper server in my Windows or iOS settings it never works. I don't understand why.
const WebSocket = require('ws')
class bot {
    constructor(server, proxy) {
        this.socket = null;
        this.server = server
        this.proxy = proxy;
        this.status = false
        this.connect()
    }
    connect() {
        this.socket = new WebSocket('wss://test:80/', {
            agent: new SocksProxyAgent(`socks://${this.proxy}`),
        })
        this.socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer'
        this.socket.onopen = this.onopen.bind(this)
        this.socket.onclose = this.onclose.bind(this)
        this.socket.onerror = this.onerror.bind(this)
    }
    onerror(err) {
        console.log('err', this.proxy)
    }
    onopen() {
        console.log('connected', this.proxy)
    }
    onclose() {
        console.log('disconnected', this.proxy)
    }
    close() {
        this.socket.close()
    }
}

If I was to use a working proxy with this it will work, why coudn't it work as a web proxy on my actual device? Thanks
